# Consume NAV Soap web service in java

Tags: java, soap, nav, microsoft-dynamics-nav

Any Lead for consuming Microsoft dyanmics NAV web service.Client has given us a WSDL file in XML format and we need to consume it in java/spring boot.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this tutorial: https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-web-service/

You'll need to export the wsdl SOAP file from NAV/BC. You create the SOAP file form the web services page.

You dont even need spring-boot to consume the web service. You just need to figure out how to setup JAXB.